# Trek Dual Sport 4 - chainring question

Tags: chainring

I have recently got hold of a Trek Dual Sport 4 but find I spend the majority of my time at the higher end of the 1x11 gears (8,9,10,11).
I am wondering if it is possible to change / upgrade the chainring to a larger size to compensate - hoping this will give a boost of top end speed too?
Any advice or suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Maybe your cadence is too low? It comes with 42 tooth chainring. At a cadence of 100rpm you should reach 51km/h. Is that really not enough? At 75rpm you’d top out at 38km/h.

Comment: Minor question - do you find that the 11 tooth gear is "not enough" and you want to change onward from there to an even harder gear ?  If not (or only rarely) then its possibly okay as-is.

Comment: With the aerodynamics of that bike, if you can maintain 40km/h,  you can go pro and get a sponsor to pay for a custom chain ring.

Comment: My 2022 Trek DS 2 gen 4 has a 68 mm road crank.

Answer (score 4):

Short version: it's complicated.

On the chainring side of the equation, it's quite hard to find components that match this kind of requirements:

- if your Dual Sport has a bottom bracket shell width of 73mm, you'll be stuck with MTB components, where finding anything bigger than 36 tooth is very very challenging. It's also not possible to use a road/gravel chainring on a MTB crank.
- if the bottom bracket shell width is 68mm, you may be able to fit road/gravel components, but then you'll have to see if there is enough clearance to do that (the chainring will be bigger and closer to the frame). That being said, even in gravel components, chainrings bigger than 42 tooth are very rare. The biggest I've seen is 44 teeth, so the gain will only be marginal. The reason being that cassettes with 10 tooth small sprockets are becoming more common, so there's no point in increasing the chainring size.

So, if you really want to improve your top speed, the best option is probably to change the cassette and the hub: a cassette with a 10 tooth small sprocket will give you a greater speed, but to install this cassette you'll need a Microspline or XD freebody (the part where the cassette is attached to the hub), which will probably require to change the whole hub, which would mean rebuilding the wheel. In the main brands, those cassettes are also only 12 speed, so you'll need to chainring your derailleur and shifter as well.

Some will also argue that your cadence is probably too low, and it might be better to work on that side of the equation: if you improve the range of the transmission, the Dual Sport is not the most aerodynamic bike: more speed means more drag, and it might be easier to achieve higher speeds that with smaller ratios.

So, in my opinion, it's a lot of complications for limited gains.

Comment: Looking at the bike specs, I think that is an MTB crankset with a 73mm BB. I can't find the specs for the crank model (the Prowheel TK01, I believe) on the manufacturer site, so I can't find the bolt circle diameter. It could be a 4-arm crank with a standard BCD, so the OP could possibly check that and shop to see if there is a 44t or 46t ring available - although the OP would also need to check if the frame has clearance for those rings, as Trek's specs don't state the frame clearance.

Comment: SRAM has 11s XD cassettes. e13 has 9-4x 11s ones too.

Comment: @WeiwenNg The 2020 version of the DS has a 73mm for sure (I have one). When looking for info to upgrade mine, I found a picture on reddit a picture of DS4 2021 BB, showing spacers (I can't find it back though). I also though about replicating the DS4 2021 transmission, but couldn't find any crankset that matches these specs. Same with individual chainrings: except the external ones of 3x cranksets, big, finding a large 1x MTB is almost impossible. And with the current supply issues, finding a such exotic part is like chasing a unicorn ;)

Comment: Thanks to all who replied.  Before making this too complicated I will work on upping my cadence to a better level and go from there.